# Best practice for makefile calling other makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile which, for a particular target, calls another Makefile.  Suppose that the main Makefile contains

```
some_dir/some_target:
    cd some_dir && make some_target
```

and that `some_dir/Makefile` contains

```
some_target: file1 file2
    do_stuff
```

Here's my conundrum: What should the dependencies be for the target in the main Makefile?  If I put no dependencies, then, according to the GNU make manual, `some_dir/Makefile` will only be invoked if `some_dir/some_target` doesn't exist.  I could instead copy the dependencies from `some_dir/Makefile`.  However, that creates the danger of later changing the dependencies in the subdirectory's Makefile and forgetting to update the main Makefile.

Is there a way to tell the main Makefile, "I don't know if the target is out of date or not.  Go ask the other Makefile"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the main Makefile, "I don't know if the target is out of date or not. Go ask the other Makefile"?

There is no provision specifically for delegating to another makefile, but you can achieve a similar result by ensuring that the recipe for the target in question is always run.  There are mechanisms and conventions for that.

The old-school approach is to declare a dependency on a target that does not exist and is never actually built.  You may see such a target being named `FORCE`, though that's only a convention.  The name is not directly significant.  Example:

```
some_dir/some_target: FORCE
    cd some_dir && make some_target

# Dummy target
FORCE:
```

As long is there is not, in fact, a file named `FORCE` in the working directory, the `FORCE` target will be considered initially out of date, so every target that directly or indirectly depends on it will be built (see also below).

There is, of course, a weakness in that: what if a file named `FORCE` actually is created?  However unlikely that may be, it screws up the whole scheme if it happens.  Some `make` implementations, notably GNU's, have an implementation-specific way to address that.  GNU's approach is to recognize a special, built-in target named `.PHONY` (do not overlook the leading `.`).  All prerequisites of `.PHONY` are considered out of date on every build, notwithstanding anything on the filesystem.  Inasmuch as `make` implementations that do not recognize that convention are unlikely to be troubled by its use, there is little drawback to putting it in play:

```
.PHONY: FORCE
```

You could also skip `FORCE` and just directly declare `some_dir/some_target` itself to be phony, as another answer suggests, but there are at least two problems with that:

- it's *not* really phony in the usual sense.  You expect that target to be built.  Declaring it phony is therefore confusing.
- if you happen to try to use that approach with a `make` that does not recognize `.PHONY`, then the whole scheme falls apart.  If you instead use an intermediate phony target (such as `FORCE`, above) then your makefile still works even with such `make`s, except in the unlikely event that a file named the same as the dummy target is created.

**But note well** that however implemented, any such scheme has a significant drawback: if you force `some_dir/some_target` be considered out of date on every build, so that the sub-`make` will be run unconditionally, then every other target that depends directly or indirectly on `some_dir/some_target` will also be rebuilt every time.  On the other hand, if you do not force it to be rebuilt, then it might not be rebuilt when it ought to be, as you already recognize.  This is the topic of the well-known paper [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.20.2572&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  As an alternative, then, you should consider *not* using recursive `make`.

Comment: "if you force some_dir/some_target be considered out of date on every build ... then every other target that depends directly or indirectly on X will also be rebuilt every time ... As an alternative, then, you should consider not using recursive make" - For cases when this is a problem worth dealing with, I'd recommend using something other than make (CMake or Meson), rather than "flattening" makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

One option consists in forcing a sub-make:

```
dummy := $(shell $(MAKE) -C some_dir some_target)

top_target: some_dir/some_target
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

"I don't know if the target is out of date or not" - you can use `.PHONY` for this:

```
.PHONY: some_dir/some_target
some_dir/some_target:
    cd some_dir && make some_target
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets:

> The prerequisites of the special target .PHONY are considered to be phony targets. When it is time to consider such a target, make will run its recipe unconditionally, regardless of whether a file with that name exists or what its last-modification time is.